# resizeColumnToContent not working with custom model and delegate

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I am using a QTreeView to display a custom model in 4 columns. This basically works, but I just can't get resizeColumnToContent to work.

I tried this

```
ui->treeSkills->header()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->treeSkills->header()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->treeSkills->header()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->treeSkills->header()->setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

and this:

```
ui->treeSkills->resizeColumnToContents(0);
ui->treeSkills->resizeColumnToContents(1);
ui->treeSkills->resizeColumnToContents(2);
ui->treeSkills->resizeColumnToContents(3);
```

Both before and after setting the data. Nothing seems to work.

One guess is that I possibly have to return a size inside model::data() when a certain role is requested. But that is not possible as the actual text/content of each cell is determined in the delegate, not in the model.

Another guess was to just change the rect size in the delegate inside paint(), like this:

```
options.rect.setWidth(options.rect.width() * 2);
p_painter->save();
p_painter->setClipRect(options.rect);

drawBackground(p_painter, options, p_index);
drawDisplay(p_painter, options, options.rect, text);
drawFocus(p_painter, options, options.rect);

p_painter->restore();
```

But, again, nothing changed.

Any ideas how to do this?
Given that layouts work so well everywhere else in Qt it is really weird that this is such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and it ended up being me setting `SizeHintRole` in the custom model:

```py
def data(self, index, role):
  ...
  if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
     return QtCore.QSize(-1, 22)
```

Here, I tried to set a fixed vertical size for all rows, and it ended up messing with the width as well. Not sure if this is the same in your case, but I suggest looking into your `data()` definition (or even `headerData()`).